# displaying a sucess message using email.js

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm wondering how I can display a "message sent successfully" message after the user has submitted the form?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Right now the message is sent but there is no success message displayed.

```
export const Contact = (props) => {
  const [{ name, email, message }, setState] = useState(initialState)

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }))
  }
  const clearState = () => setState({ ...initialState })

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(name, email, message)
    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        'service_8cyr6cf', 'template_0koo5jf', e.target, 'TtcKG0LCV4-mP5FnV'
      )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.text)
          clearState()
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text)
        }
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`emailjs` only handles the sending email part. If you want to display something on your UI, you need to create some HTML to display it.
Something like:

```js
export const Contact = (props) => {
  const [{ name, email, message }, setState] = useState(initialState)
  const [statusMessage, setStatusMessage] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }))
  }
  const clearState = () => setState({ ...initialState })

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(name, email, message)
    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        'service_8cyr6cf', 'template_0koo5jf', e.target, 'TtcKG0LCV4-mP5FnV'
      )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.text, result.status);
          clearState();
          setStatusMessage("Email sent success");
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
          setStatusMessage(`${error.text} happened`);
        }
      )
  }

  return 
  (
     <div>
       <form></form>
       <p>{statusMessage}</p>
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Had to change message to Message as message had already been declared const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

Comment: Oh sorry I did not notice `message` had already been used. I changed to `const [statusMessage, setStatusMessage] = useState("")`. Generally, I would try to avoid variable name starting with uppercase (like Message)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can add something like setTimeout() function for disappearing the message status after a certain of time

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(name, email, message)
  emailjs
    .sendForm(
      "service_8cyr6cf",
      "template_0koo5jf",
      e.target,
      "TtcKG0LCV4-mP5FnV"
    )
    .then(
      (result) => {
        console.log(result.text, result.status)
        clearState()
        setStatusMessage("Email sent successfully")

        setTimeout(() => {
          setStatusMessage("")
        }, 3000) // Hide the message after 3 seconds
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error.text)
        setStatusMessage("Failed to send Email. Please try again.")
        setTimeout(() => {
          setStatusMessage("")
        }, 3000) // Hide the message after 3 seconds
      }
    )
}
```